# Best way of SELECT based on DATE in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a database table with column DATETIME called 'entry_date', such as...

```
ID  entry_date
1   2012-10-13
2   2012-10-14
3   2012-10-15
4   2012-10-20
5   2012-10-20
6   2012-10-21
```

Whats the best way of echoing out the result for based on DATE in PHP/MYSQL, so i get just the results for this week so 2012-10-15 > 2012-10-21, but obviously i can't just code that out because days change, everyday :) so how would you do that in php so tomorrow the condition for this week would be 2012-10-16 > 2012-10-22

Comment: What is your question? The title and the last paragraph seem to ask different things. And what have you tried?

Comment: I have edited the question, tired to explain myself better, i haven't tried anything as i have no idea.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For today, use

```
where date(`entry_date`) = curdate()
```

For this month,

```
where month(`entry_date`) = month(curdate()) 
and  year(`entry_date`) = year(curdate())
```

For this week

```
WHERE `entry_date` 
BETWEEN (CURDATE() - Interval DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) day) 
AND (CURDATE() - Interval DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) day + Interval 1 week)
```

Above query is good for understanding. But not good for performance point of view. See the bellow modified one. Its far better.

```
SET @s:=(CURDATE() - Interval DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) day)
SET @e:=(CURDATE() - Interval DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) day + Interval 1 week)
SELECT ....  WHERE `entry_date` BETWEEN @s AND @e
```

Here DAYOFWEEK function returns an integer number starting from 1=Sunday. So your weeks will be counted as Saturday as starting date. If you want Monday add `+ Interval 2 day` with Interval.

It can be also simplified to the following. But it does not support any day as first day of week. So its not portable to all culture.

```
where yearweek(`entry_date`) = yearweek(curdate())
```

Comment: Can you add this year please?

Comment: @CarlRydings check how 'this month' is calculated.

Comment: Might also want to mention the function `WEEK`, which works as expected.

Comment: @VincentSavard I forgot that. but `WEEK` function does not let you customize first day of the week for every culture. It just supports Sunday and Monday. My firstday of week is Saturday

Comment: Those all work except this week, im using... SELECT * FROM entry WHERE `entry_date` BETWEEN (CURDATE() - Interval DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE()) day) AND (CURDATE() - Interval DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())+ Interval +2 week) ...is that right, i need it to start Monday as im in the UK which needs to be monday 15th to sunday 21st

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im if i use... where yearweek(entry_date) = yearweek(curdate()) ...for week, how do i make it start on monday?

Comment: @CarlRydings `YEARWEEK` does not support that. BTW I fixed the problem with `this week` condition.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: You can't customize it fully, but `WEEK` accepts a second parameter which lets you set the first day of the week. It only supports Sunday and Monday, though, but I assume it covers a large part of MySQL's user base.

Comment: Don't run functions on your columns in the WHERE clause - mysql can't use the index!  You need to end up with something that looks like `WHERE entry_date between ? and ?`, where the two params are constants.

Comment: @AlainCollins good suggestion. The whole query can be optimized if I just use variables with `set`. I knew that. Now I just added that. Thanks a lot